# I cannot use material-ui components after update to material-ui@0.15.0-beta.1

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I got this message in my console:

> Failed Context Types: Required context `muiTheme` was not specified in
>   `AppBar`
>
> AppBar.js:158 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepareStyles'
>   of undefined

I just have an AppBar in my Component
I think it should work but...
here my very simple code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppBar} from 'material-ui';


    export class MyComponent extends React.Component {

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <AppBar
                        title="Title"
                    />

                </div>
            );
        }

    }
```

thanks for helping...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With material-ui@0.15.0.beta-1 a few things were changed.

You can have a look on the link below for more details.
https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Therefore with those changes your code becomes:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
    import baseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme';
    import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

        export class MyComponent extends React.Component {

            getChildContext() {
                return { muiTheme: getMuiTheme(baseTheme) };
            }

            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <AppBar
                            title="Title"
                        />

                    </div>
                );
            }        
        }

        MyComponent.childContextTypes = {
            muiTheme: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        };
```

Comment: Why do they make it more complicated? It would be great if I can write less code to get it to work.

Comment: I've just swapped from Bootstrap to MUI and now I see this... Crazy that everything needs to be wrapped liek this, is there a way to do it globally I wonder?

Comment: how to do to make title clickable?

Answer (score 20):

now in the 0.15.0 you can use muiThemeProvider:

```
...

import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import MyAwesomeReactComponent from './MyAwesomeReactComponent';

const App = () => (
 <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <MyAwesomeReactComponent />
 </MuiThemeProvider>
)

...
```

So you do not have to provide context to childrens manualy.
More info in [documentation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/usage).

Comment: @BruceSun yes I am using it in 2 projects.

Comment: I found the reason - it doesn't work if I define my component using React.createClass(), but works if I create a ES6 class extending React.Component. I didn't find any documentation about this though.

Comment: @BruceSun - I believe it is recommended that you start defining your React components with the ES2015 syntax henceforth.

Comment: But this doesn't work with jest testing individual components. Am I missing something.

Comment: @Viraths you can create helper function which will wrap your tested component with MuiThemeProvider if you need it. And then use wrapper.dive() to get to the actual component instead of that provider...

Comment: the question has 'appbar' but in your example you dont' use appbar

Comment: @stackdave you can put AppBar instead of MyAwesomeReactComponent

Answer (score 5):

Import MuiThemeProvider and then wrap the material-ui component AppBar with MuiThemeProvider.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return ( 
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
          <AppBar title = "Title" />
        </div> 
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```