# Change tab content using router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-component, react-routing

I am making a react application. Can I change the "tab content area" on a button click using react-router. I have two tabs. I want to change content of one of the tab when I click a button. Everything else on the page should remain same but the content of the tab. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very knowledgeable on react-router but I would recommend using [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs). It's very neat and extremely easy to implement (albeit, there are some [changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953711/i-cannot-use-material-ui-components-after-update-to-material-ui0-15-0-beta-1) you need to make before using it).

If you still want to use react-router for your tabs, I did find a few solutions that might help you.

[Possible solution #1](https://github.com/tleunen/react-mdl/issues/355)

[Possible solution #2](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1056)

Comment: I am using material ui tabs only. But I want to change what I see in a tab to change on a button click. For example: There is a list view in my one of my tab and I want it to fade out and something else to replace that are when I click a button. What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: Can you edit your original post and show what you have done? At least I can know what to explain.